# Play a .mp3 item in a listbox using VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I am learning to make a mp3 player with visual basic. All i have done is  that i have made a visual basic application in Visual Studio using windows-media-Player Plugin. Next what i did was to attach a Ms Access database to the listbox to show some songs in the listbox.

The listbox is showing my list of songs.

Now what i want is that whenever i double-Click a song name in that listbox, it should play it in the plugin of my app.

I tried using Hyperlinks in access but couldn't find any useful information about how to use it.

Please Help.

Comment: You need to store a Full File Path in your Access database in a regular text column or a memo column. Don't use the hyperlink field type for this. In fact, I wouldn't use the Hyperlink data type for anything.

Comment: After storing my path in the Access database in a regular text column, How to use it to open in my VS basic application listbox using my WMPlib.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [`WMPLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This allows you to create and control a Windows Media Player Controller. You pass it either the path of the .mp3 you wish to play directly or, for a better experience, create a playlist and pass that to the player.

The page I've linked to has some VB.NET as well as C# code.

```
Player = New WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer
Player.URL = url
Player.controls.play()
```

where `url` is the full path to the file you wish to play.

Comment: How to send a link to Player.URL from my access database ?

Comment: @user1263375 - the link is just the path. So you need to either store the full path in the database or have a way of recreating it in your application.

Comment: yea i got it. But now i am struct how to recreate path in visual basic

Comment: @user1263375 - there are plenty of questions on Stack Overflow about creating paths.